# Unable to write INI file in Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, ini

I have a small program that keeps updating data every second like a mentoring software installed on my Windows 7 64-bit PC. The thing is that I tried it on other PCs and different OS like Mac and Windows XP and Vista, and things are just fine. The problem shows up when I use it on my new machine "Windows 7 64-bit" giving an error:

> ** unable to write file.ini **

I have BitDefender on the same PC, but not sure if BitDefender is the one that is blocking the file not to be written or it is Windows itself causing that...

Any idea how to resolve this issue??

Comment: What language is your app written in? What line of code is generating the error you're showing us? There's pretty much *nothing* in your question to give us anything to go on.... =)

Comment: oK, first the file is located in the root: C:\file.init , and second: the language is English. and third, there is no error in the program code, but it is a java message giving this error... so... what do you think?

Comment: I think that "language is English" is less than helpful when you're asking a question on a progamming Q&A site. To be clear, I meant what **programming language** did you write your application in?. Also, **without showing us the code that's generating the error, you cannot hope to get a good answer here**.

Comment: ok, now I got it. you mean what language the software is written. It is vb. I believe it is windows 7 issue because I see bunch of similar issues in the net talking about being unable to write ini file in win7... unfortunately, I can't open the program and I don't how.. it is something I bought from the net... And as I said, it works fine on other PCs expect the one that is win7 OS based...

Comment: In that case, your question is **off topic** for Stack Overflow. I'd suggest you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions to see what **is** on topic =) In a nut-shell: *Stack Overflow is for asking programming questions, not general computer support* =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to start your Application with administration-rights. Creating a file on C:\ isn't possible, if you don't have ne needed rights. Try to change the UAC-settings or write your file in another directory (Also not "Program files", "Windows" ... systemfolders)

Comment: I bit you are right, I thought of it as windows 7 issue. I noticed this since I purchased the new OS... I will look for this and see if works. Thanks